# Elasticsearch is not working after configurations in Magento admin

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

**Installed details: Magento 2.4.2, Elasticsearch 7.6.0, Ububtu 20.04.**

Elasticsearch is working on localhost:9200.

```
{
  "name" : "magento",
  "cluster_name" : "my-application",
  "cluster_uuid" : "bp8QVARQTxavGac9XSUadw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.6.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "7f634e9f44834fbc12724506cc1da681b0c3b1e3",
    "build_date" : "2020-02-06T00:09:00.449973Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.4.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I made the necessary configurations in the **Stores/Configurations/Catalog/Catalog/Catalog Search**.

[image]

then `php bin/magento cache:clean` and `bin/magento indexer:reindex`, then tried to search.

**But the problem is that the search does not work on the Luma page:**

[image]

I checked http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices?v:

```
health status index                            uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   magento2_es_demo5x1_product_1_v2 W4E0HOGtTd6Y4LCBWvo3-w   1   1          0            0       283b           283b
yellow open   magento2_product_1_v9            YerIXZhrSii_b5wxarJ6hA   1   1          0            0       283b           283b
```

checked http://127.0.0.1:9200/magento2_product_1_v9/_search?pretty=true:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

(I can provide the necessary details).

Just started learning Magento and ElasticSearch, so I really ask the community to tell me in detail what to do to make ElasticSearch work in my Magento project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Elasticsearch search server is working and Magento 2 can communicate with it which is great, but looking at the tests you did the magento2 index is empty.

Make sure you have ran the indexers

```
bin/magento index:reindex
```

or just to reindex search

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
```

Test your search again from the command line (or browser) with

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/magento2_product_1_vXXX/_search?q=name:simple&pretty'
```

http://127.0.0.1:9200/magento2_product_1_vXXX/_search?q=name:simple&pretty:

Comment: bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext  (rebuilt successfully ).   
the second command throws an error(magento2_product_1_vXXX/ magento2_product_1_v9) -> (        "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason" : "no such index [magento2_product_2_vXXX]",). What should be my next steps

Comment: You must add the index name from your server - you see it with the _cat/indices command, or simply try your frontend search for "simple" again.

Comment: By the looks of it, you have the index created but it has no products indexed inside it. Probably a redundant thing, but you do have products which are enabled and set with visibility 'Catalog, Search' OR 'Search', right?

Answer (score 0):

To verify that Elasticsearch is working, enter the following command on the server on which it is running:

curl -XGET ':9200/_cat/health?v&pretty'
A message similar to the following is displayed:

epoch      timestamp cluster       status node.total node.data shards pri relo init unassign pending_tasks
1519701563 03:19:23  elasticsearch green           1         1      0   0    0    0        0             0

Document:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/elasticsearch/configure-magento.html
https://vrajeshpatel.in/2020/08/23/magento-2-4-0-getting-error-could-not-validate-a-connection-to-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selected Website in the sales Channel section of edit stock[image]